# Sails.js Download File To Client

Tags: javascript, http, sails.js

In my Sails.js(v0.12) app we generate a file into the myApp/downloads/uuid-filename.ext. However I cannot find a solid answer on how to download the file to client.

My first idea was to pass the uuid to the user and allow them to download it from the URL. However I'm unsure how to access the files from the client even if I know the full file name.

The second idea was to stream the content to the user, but without the Express.js "res.download()" function it seems impossible. I found "res.attachment" on the sails.js documentation. However the example was not helpful in the slightest.

How can I download a file from my API(Sails.js v0.12) to my client(AngularJS)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually create a stream of your file and use pipe to send it

here is a working code

```
    let filename = req.param("filename");
    let filepath = req.param("filepath");

    let file = require('path').resolve(sails.config.appPath+'//'+filepath)

    if(fs.existsSync(file))
    {
          res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=' + filename);

          let filestream = fs.createReadStream(file);
          filestream.pipe(res);

    }else{
        res.json({error : "File not Found"});
    }
```

this is tested with sailsJS (0.12) and AngularJS

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way which I could think of is generate the file in downloads folder inside `assets` folder.

This way if you provide the download link as `http://<url>/downloads/<uuid>.<ext>`, it will automatically download if the file exists, else will throw `404`.

Comment: I didn't find downloads folder in assets ,Do I have to create new one

Comment: Yes. You can create a new one.