# Downloading file from a sails endpoint

Tags: javascript, sails.js

I am building a server using sails which is supposed to pull the pdf content from an endpoint and  send it in the response. How do I do this
This is what I have tried so far:

```
fn: async function (inputs, exits) {
    const downloadLink = this.req.param('link');
    const pdf = (await axios.get(downloadLink, { responseType: 'blob' 
    })).data
    if (!downloadLink || !pdf) {
       throw 'not found';
    }
    this.res.attachment('abc').send(pdf);
    return exits.success();
}
```

This, however, does not seem to work. I have pdf.js installed in my chrome which displays pdf content. When I try to run the code above, it tries to open a file but ends up showing the error "invalid pdf content"

Comment: Have u set header application/pdf in content type?

Comment: AFAIK the `this.res.attachment` statement does that on it's own. https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/response-res/res-attachment

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50142797/sails-js-download-file-to-client

Comment: @JagadeshaNH the link you posted specifies how to read a file from the file system and then pipe it to the response. In my case I already have the content I'm not sure how to pass it in the response.

Answer (score 0):

The following seems to do the trick:

```
fn: async function (inputs, exits) {
    const downloadLink = this.req.param('link');
    const pdf = (await axios.get(downloadLink, { responseType: 'arraybuffer' 
    })).data
    if (!downloadLink || !pdf) {
       throw 'not found';
    }
    this.res.attachment('abc.pdf').send(pdf);
    return exits.success();
}
```

Note the change in response type from `blob` to `arraybuffer`.